# The unbeatable $\int e^{1/\cos(x)} dx$ integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Is there any way to express this in non-elementary functions?
$$ \int e^{1/\cos(x)} dx$$ 
And/or to calculate this definite integrals?
$$ \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} e^{1/\cos(x)} dx$$
$$ \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/ 2} e^{1/\cos(x)} dx$$

Added later:

First integral does not converges, but second on seems to be smooth function and WolframAlpha thinks it is approximately $0.656573$.

[image: exp(sec(x)) graph]

Really, nothing is known about this function?

$$f(x)=\int_{\pi/2}^x e^{1/\cos(x)} dx; x \in ({\pi/2} ,{3\pi/ 2}]$$

Comment: No, they're unbeatable.

Comment: Those definite integrals don't converge, do they?  Since $\sec x$ blows up at $x=\pm \pi/2$, and $\exp(\sec x)$ is even worse.

Comment: The definite integral can be expressed in terms of [modified Struve function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedStruveFunction.html) $L_{n}(x)$ and [modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) $K_{n}(x)$.
$$\int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2}e^{1/\cos x}dx = \pi \big( 1 - ( L_{-1}(1)K_0(1) + L_{0}(1)K_1(1)) \big)$$
Numerically, WolframAlpha evaluate RHS as 
$$\sim 0.656572956342236706015778669836974388126820426372711007254860$$

Comment: Also see [sievert integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert_integral)

Answer (score 3):

$e^\frac{1}{\cos(x)} \ge e^\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-x} \ge 1+\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}-x}$ for any $x \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2})$ because $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x) = \sin(x) \le x$ for any $x \ge 0$

Therefore $\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} e^\frac{1}{\cos(x)} \text{ dx} = \infty$ and hence also the first definite integral.

The second integral is, as you say, continuous and hence integrable. I don't know about its value, nor the indefinite integral.

[Edit: I misread the second indefinite integral in my original answer.]

Answer (score 2):

The indefinite integral is not an elementary function.  This can be proven using the Risch algorithm.